# Accessing a data.frame subset by specific dates generates NA

Tags: r, macos

I have a data.frame where each column contains the monthly returns on various stocks since 2014 and the first column contains the observation date. I need to access the returns for those stocks on specific dates (say 2018-01-31, or between 2014-02-03 and 2018-01-01) in order to compute several statistics. The data set looks like:

```
       Date           aer  api            ar           ccj           cve          fcu
2014-02-20  0.1114229582 <NA>  0.0274509804  0.0458167331 -0.0684382963  0.245283019
2014-02-21  0.1486823856 <NA>  0.0364592781  0.0434139122 -0.0666423889  0.196261682
2014-02-24  0.1714285714 <NA>  0.0701561065  0.0552788845 -0.0488694384  0.284313725
2014-02-25  0.1584653878 <NA>  0.0585154416  0.1024531025 -0.0465631929  0.317307692
```

When I calculate the covariance matrix for the returns on specific date ranges, the assignment works correctly. However, when I try to perform the same operation for one particular date in order to multiply that row of returns by another vector I get NAs

```
library(timeSeries)
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
library(ggplot2)
library(caTools)
library(dplyr)
library(portfolio)
library(fBasics)
library(zoo)

data.returns$Date<-as.Date(data.returns$Date,format="%Y-%m-%d")
data.returns_m$Date<-as.Date(data.returns_m$Date,format="%Y-%m- 
%d")
# defining monthly dates to compute returns
date_enddec17<-as.Date("2017-12-29")
date_endjan18<-as.Date("2018-01-31")
date_endfeb18<-as.Date("2018-02-28")
date_endmar18<-as.Date("2018-03-29")
date_endapr18<-as.Date("2018-04-30")
date_endmay18<-as.Date("2018-05-31")
date_endjun18<-as.Date("2018-06-29")
date_endjul18<-as.Date("2018-07-31")
date_endaug18<-as.Date("2018-08-31")
date_endsep18<-as.Date("2018-09-28")
date_endoct18<-as.Date("2018-10-31")
date_endnov18<-as.Date("2018-11-30")
date_enddic18<-as.Date("2018-12-31")

date_list <- c(date_enddec17, date_endjan18, date_endfeb18, 
date_endmar18, date_endapr18, date_endmay18, date_endjun18, 
           date_endjul18, date_endaug18, date_endsep18, 
date_endoct18, date_endnov18, date_enddic18)

# initialising the lists for the statistics
Covariance <- list()
W_gmv <- list()
ret_m <- list()

# for loop to calculate the statistics for each date
local <- 0
for (i in date_list) {
  local <- local + 1
  Covariance[[local]] <- 
cov(na.omit(data.returns[data.returns$Date>=i-365*4 & 
data.returns$Date<=i,2:ncol(data.returns)]))
      W_gmv[[local]<-  (solve(Covariance[[local]])%*%e)%*%solve(t(e)%*%solve(Covariance[[local]])%*%e)

      ret_m[[local]] <- 1 + t(as.matrix(as.numeric(data.returns_m[data.returns_m$Date==i+30,-1]))) %*%W_gmv[[local]]

}
```

I expected to obtain a list (ret_m) with 13 numbers, each of them representing the monthly return for that specific date, instead I got a list of 13 NAs. Surprisingly this didn't happen with the covariance calculation (first command in the loop), which worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want monthly returns, have you tried quantmod::monthlyReturn()?

If your data is in a dataframe you might need to convert it to an xts object first. The timekt package is helpful to convert from data frames to xts objects, or other way around. Try this:

```
library(timekt)
my_xts <- timekt::tk_xts(my_dataframe)
quantmod::monthlyReturn(my_xts$ar)
```